# C# - List the name of each file in a directory into an Array?

Tags: c#, file

How would one list the files in a directory into an Array? Files only, I could care less for folders. I know in python it's:

```
for file in os.listdir('Blah'):
    #BlahBlahBlah
```

However, I'm not sure how I would go about doing so in C#. 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 12):

Use [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) method

```
string[] filesArray = Directory.GetFiles("yourpath");
```

> Returns the names of files (including their paths) in the specified
>   directory.

Remember to include [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx)

You can also use [Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) to search files by specifying search patterns. Something like:

```
string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "X*");
```

return all files starting with Character `X`

You may use:

```
if(Directory.Exists("yourpath"))
```

to check if the path exists

Answer (score 5):

```
using System.IO;    
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("PATH");
OR
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("PATH","*.docx",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
OR
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("PATH","*.pdf",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
OR
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("PATH","*.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try following...Use System.IO directory

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\MyDir\");
```